# How to remove extension (and prefix) of filenames using `find` at the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, filenames

I've written this little bit of a command that recursively finds the class names of compiled java.  It recursively finds all *.class files which I then attempt to make class names from by replacing the '/' with '.', stripping the prefix, etc.

`class_files=$(find ./build-tests -d -name \*.class -print | tr "\/" "." | cut -c15-10000)`

My bash scripting knowledge is very beginner.  But after searching around a little I've come across the idea of using ${i%%.class} to remove the .class suffix, but I'm not sure how to add that to the piped version of the command line?  Is this possible?  Or do I need to use a loop and build up an array and then join the array, and all of that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the `-d` option to `find` indicates in your invocation, but perhaps this is what you want:

```
find ./build-tests -name "*.class" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -Ifoo basename foo .class
```